# Split list into sublists using value as the delimiter

Tags: c#, list, linq

Almost every single programming language has a string split function:

```
foreach (var partition in "12304508".Split("0"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(partition);
}
// Output:
// 123
// 45
// 8
```

Is there any way to do the same but for a generic list instead of a string, i.e. something like:

```
int[] nums = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 8}; // can be any generic type instead of int
foreach (var partition in nums.SomeLinqFunctionHere(0))
{
    Console.WriteLine(partition);
}
// Expected output:
// int[]{1, 2, 3}
// int[]{4, 5}
// int[]{8}
```

What's the easiest way of doing that?

Comment: With a generic type, would you still expect the item you are splitting on to be dropped? For example, if you passed in a list of `Uri` or `Foo` objects?

Comment: @DavidG the same as string.split(), i.e. dropped

Answer (score 1):

This should work and is flexible in a way that you can split by conditions instead of only values:

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> SplitBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Predicate<T> matchFilter)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    foreach(T item in sequence)
    {
        if (matchFilter(item))
        {
            yield return list;
            list = new List<T>();
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
    }
    if (list.Any()) yield return list;
}
```

Use:

```
int[] nums = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 8 }; // can be any generic type instead of int
foreach (var partition in nums.SplitBy(i => i == 0))
{
     Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", partition));
}
```

Comment: Depending on your need you can add a `if (list.Any())` before the first yield too otherwise it returns an empty list when the first element match, or two consecutive element matches. Also, if you want the matching element to be included as the first element in the list, add it in the `new List<T> { item };` inside the same condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```cs
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T[]> SplitEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T byValue)
    {
        return SplitEnumerable(enumerable, byValue, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T[]> SplitEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T byValue, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        List<T> buffer = new List<T>();
        foreach (var v in enumerable)
        {
            if (comparer.Equals(v, byValue))
            {
                yield return buffer.ToArray();
                buffer.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                buffer.Add(v);
            }
        }

        yield return buffer.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, why allocate arrays and lists, wouldn't `IEnumrable<IEnumerable<T>>` be better.

Comment: I can return anything. But question was about arrays.